# echo and php isn't working, how do i fix it?

Tags: php

can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code because I can't still understand what's wrong here. am trying to use PHP in my HTML code and I don't know what's wrong it ain't giving me the result

I already tried what I can but the code isn't still working

```
<div class="section__content section__content--p30">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                        <?php 
                            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                                echo "hi";
                            }
                        ?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" id="first_name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" id="last_name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </div>
                     </form>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
```

that's supposed to echo 'hi' if the submit button is clicked but nothing is showing don't know what went wrong

Comment: I realise you are probably frustrated, but please no swearing in a question

Comment: also you're input type="submit" doesn't have a name attribute .. there's your issue

Comment: @treyBake you are blessed man, Thanks that's the issue

Comment: i will advice you don't put the php code logic inside the <form> tag. that also can be an issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly i was really frustrate like you said but i do apologise

Comment: @SegunEmmanuel understood, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your problem, you need to add `name='submit'` in your  button as:

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">
```

Otherwise, you will get undefined index notice.

This will only apply for your condition:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

You can also use [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) here, [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) will check the array count of `$_POST`:

```
if (count($_POST) > 0) {
```

Comment: it's redundant to use count on $_POST just use `!empty()` on your var

Comment: thanks man the name attribute was the issue

Comment: @treyBake wasn't i suppose to get an error since like " you will get undefined index notice." or something but i don't get any error, it was just blank why?

Comment: @hak i was suppose to get an error like " you will get undefined index notice." or something but i don't get any error, it was just blank why?

Comment: It was incorrect to say that you'd receive a notice. That is the purpose of `isset()`; it checks to see if something is defined, without throwing any warnings. @Devintel

Comment: @Devintel: becuase u r not using php error reporting in your code, thats way you are not getting errors